# Q: Dirichlet Problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to show that $\psi(x,y) = \pi + 2Arg(z)$, $\ -\pi < Arg(z) < \pi$,

is a solution of the DP on the upper half plane $[{(x,y) \in \Re^2: y > 0}]$ with limiting value $\pi$ on that part of the boundary where $x > 0$ and limiting value $3\pi$ on that part of the boundary where $x<0$.

Now I've been trying to form the standard solution of $a + bArg(z)$, slightly confused why $Arg(z)=0$ for the $x > 0$ boundary and $Arg(z)=\pi$ for $x < 0$.

Comment: $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is the angle between $z$ (as a vector) and the positive real axis.

Comment: The last statement you have wrote is true only when we have zero imaginary part. If you ask about that, i will say simply: Always we measure an angle $\theta$ between a real and imaginary parts of a  complex number $z$, starting from the positive $x$-axis and rotate the angle until we arrive to the required complex number $(x,y)$. So when $y=0$ and $x>0$, we don't have any angle (we don't move; stay on the positive real axis). And when $y=0$ and $x<0$ then we are on the negative real axis so the angle is form the positive to the negative is $\pi$.